# QT creator simple C++ program runs from IDE but not from command lne

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting errors running a simple c++ program from qt creator. I can build and run successfully in the QT creator IDE but when I try to run the .exe from the command line I am getting missing .dll file error.

I have this compiler bin directory in my path so it builds and runs in ide OK.
Is there some type way to make the built .exe use the same dlls as the ide run?
any other ideas? thanks

Comment: see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qozxqSZQEg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're missing the path of the compiler.

You could add to Windows system **PATH**  environment variable your compiler `bin` directory.

As an example, compiling an Qt application with MSVC2013, it runs successfully from command line adding `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin` to system **PATH** environment variable.

You should take into account that it's not a good idea to permanently add Qt's bin folder to the PATH. If you try to launch an application that's built with a different version of Qt, you could load the wrong DLLs and crash.

Remember to log out or at least to close the command prompt before launching the application (for the changes to take effect).

Comment: It's not a good idea to permanently add Qt's _bin_ folder to the **PATH**. If you try to launch an application that's built with a different version of Qt, you could load the wrong DLLs and crash.

Comment: I don't even stated the way to go set the environment variable in windows. The question was simple: Why the error 'X' was happening. I answered him that adding the environment variable to the PATH solves his problem. On the other hand, I updated the answer taking your comment into account